# How to replace value in sequences of a boolean list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list like this:

```
list_1 = [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False]
```

In this list, there are sequences that start with a `False` and end with a `True`. I need help to implement replacing values of this list in this way:

- Replace `False` values of these sequences with a `-2^k` series. The `True` value after the last `False` of each sequence is `+2^k`, with `k` as the position of the value in a sequence.
- Other `True` values that don't belong to any of those sequences will retain value `1`.

The output looks like this:

```
list_2 = [1, -1, 2, -1, 2, 1, 1, -1, -2, -4, 8, 1, -1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
# turn data into series
s = pd.Series(list_1)

# mark the blocks ending with True
blocks = s.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()

# compute the positions within blocks and raise to power 2
powers = 2**s.groupby(blocks).cumcount()

#output:
np.where(s, 1,-1)*powers.values
```

Output:

```
array([ 1, -1,  2, -1,  2,  1,  1, -1, -2, -4,  8,  1, -1])
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks!